# nav link background hover does not work in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

This is my first post.  I am having a problem with the background color when I hover in a nav ul li a.  It works well in mozilla but for some reason in chrome, only some of the menu items change on hover.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

    $link = mysql_connect ("localhost", "pouredin_web", "Asdfgh.12345") or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
    mysql_select_db("pouredin_web", $link);

    //$Sql = "select * from news where status = 1 and web_id = ".$web_id." and pdate_in < NOW() and pdate_out > NOW() and ntype = 'Evento' order by nlevel, pdate_in desc limit 0,3 ";

    $Sql = "select * from contents";

    $data = array();
    $result = mysql_query($Sql,$link);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[$row["name"]] = $row["ntext"];
        //echo $row["name"].'<br>';
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Landed by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EPDM Polmers | EPDM Rubber Granules | Poured-In-Place Rubber</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

        <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/BackToTop.jquery.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
            <div class="keywords"><?php echo $data["topText"] ?></div><!--end keywords-->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/epdm-logo.png" class="image-full" ></a></div>
<div id="chris"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/ISO9001.jpg" class="image-full" ></a></div>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.php"><span>HOME</span></a><li>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.php"><span>OUR COMPANY</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.php"><span>PRODUCTS</span></a>


                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"<span>EPDM Rubber Granules</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="airethane-polyurethane-products.php">Polyurethane Binder</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                            <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"><span>EPDM RUBBER</span></a>

                            <li><a href="resources.php"><span>DATA SHEETS</span></a></li>



                        </ul>


                    </nav>


                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!--end container-->
            </header>


CSS FILE

    /* Header */

    #page-wrapper {
        padding-top: 0em;
    }

    #header {


    }

        #header #logo{ display:block; float:left; max-width:100px; margin: 25px auto;

        }

               #chris { display:block; float:right; max-width:100px; margin: 25px auto;

        }




        #header nav { margin-top:3.5em; display:block; float:right; background:url(../../images/nav-tail.gif) repeat-x top; 
        }

            #header nav ul {
                margin: 0; padding:0;
            }

                #header nav ul li {
                    display: block;
                    float:left;
                    margin: 0; padding:0;
                     background:url(../../images/nav-border.gif) right center no-repeat;
                }
                #header nav ul li:last-child { background:none;}
                #header nav ul li a{ padding:0.9em 2.85em;}
                    #header nav ul li a, #header nav ul li span {
                        border: 0;
                        color: inherit;
                        display: block;
                        height: inherit;
                        line-height: inherit;
                        outline: 0;
                    }

                #header nav ul li.current {  color: #FFF;
    background: rgb(76,76,76);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 54%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(54%,rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(19,19,19,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1)     0%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 54%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 54%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 54%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 54%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);}        

                #nav ul li a:hover {background: #333;}

                #header nav ul li:hover { background:#333; }    
                #header nav ul li:hover a{color:#FFF !important;}   
                        #header nav ul li a:not(.button):before, #header nav ul li span:not(.button):before {
                            margin-right: 0.5em;
                        }







                        #header nav ul li.active > a, #header nav ul li.active         > span {
                            color: #fff; background:#333;
                        }

    #header nav ul li > ul {
                            display: none;
                        }
```

Comment: works fine? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBQPVx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tried to edit some of your code for formatting. Came accross this in your code:

```
...
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php"><span>HOME</span></a>
    <li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.php"><span>OUR COMPANY</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="products.php"><span>PRODUCTS</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php" <span>EPDM Rubber Granules</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="airethane-polyurethane-products.php">Polyurethane Binder</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"><span>EPDM RUBBER</span></a>
          <li><a href="resources.php"><span>DATA SHEETS</span></a></li>
</ul>
...
```

Right away, you're missing lots of your closing tags.

An `<li>` tag needs to be closed with a `</li>` tag. For valid html. It's possible some browsers were able to render this and allow your css to function (IDK how) and maybe chrome wasn't. Thats a guess anywho...

If you can fix some of those issues and are still having problems. Let us know and we'll be happy to help.

Below is the fixed snippet of the above. However the rest of your html might not be valid HTML still.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.php"><span>OUR COMPANY</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="products.php"><span>PRODUCTS</span></a> </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php" <span>EPDM Rubber Granules</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="airethane-polyurethane-products.php">Polyurethane Binder</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"><span>EPDM RUBBER</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="resources.php"><span>DATA SHEETS</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You know what, I had tried that but not the way you did.  I messed with the code some more and it worked if I close all of the li tags except the tag after "Polyurethane Binder".  Don't ask me why.  Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: @webdevsd Yay! Glad to help! Please mark my answer as the solution. Goodluck with your development :)

Comment: @webdevsd The reason that nothing works after "Polyurethane Binder" Is because its actually invalid HTML in its current state. You cannot have an `ul` tag within a ul. You are only allow to have `li` tags within a `ul` tag. Hope that helps some more :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this exactly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
        Landed by HTML5 UP
        html5up.net | @ajlkn
    -->
<html>

<head>
    <title>EPDM Polmers | EPDM Rubber Granules | Poured-In-Place Rubber</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/BackToTop.jquery.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="keywords">
            <?php echo $data[ "topText"] ?>
        </div>
        <!--end keywords-->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/epdm-logo.png" class="image-full">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="chris">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/ISO9001.jpg" class="image-full">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php"><span>HOME</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.php"><span>OUR COMPANY</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdwn"><a href="products.php"><span>PRODUCTS</span></a>


                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"><span>EPDM Rubber Granules</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="airethane-polyurethane-products.php">Polyurethane Binder</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="ecolastic-epdm-granules.php"><span>EPDM RUBBER</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="resources.php"><span>DATA SHEETS</span></a>
                        </li>



                    </ul>


                </nav>


                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <!--end container-->
        </header>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Paste this css:

```
<style>
    #page-wrapper {
        padding-top: 0em;
    }
    #header {} #header #logo {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        max-width: 100px;
        margin: 25px auto;
    }
    #chris {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        max-width: 100px;
        margin: 25px auto;
    }
    #header nav {
        margin-top: 3.5em;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        background: url(../../images/nav-tail.gif) repeat-x top;
    }
    #header nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #header nav ul li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: url(../../images/nav-border.gif) right center no-repeat;
    }
    #header nav ul li:last-child {
        background: none;
    }
    #header nav ul li a {
        padding: 0.9em 2.85em;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    #header nav ul li a,
    #header nav ul li span {
        border: 0;
        color: inherit;
        display: block;
        height: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        outline: 0;
    }
    #header nav ul li.current {
        color: #FFF;
        background: rgb(76, 76, 76);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 54%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)), color-stop(54%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 54%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 54%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 54%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 43, 43, 1) 54%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
    }
    #nav ul li:hover a {
        background: #333;
    }
    #header nav ul li:hover {
        background: #333;
    }
    #header nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #FFF !important;
    }
    #header nav ul li a:not(.button):before,
    #header nav ul li span:not(.button):before {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
    #header nav ul li.active > a,
    #header nav ul li.active > span {
        color: #fff;
        background: #333;
    }
    #header nav ul li > ul {
        max-width: 230px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
    }
    #header nav ul li > ul > li {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #header nav ul li > ul > li > a {
        padding: 10px 10px;
        background: #037dc8;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #header nav ul li > ul > li:hover > a {
        background: #548c0a;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #header nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .dropdwn > a::before {
        content: "▼";
        position: absolute;
        left: 175px;
    }
    .dropdwn > a {
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if there is any query?